# Redux store is updated but UI is not

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue with my vote score on comments. I can see in Redux Devtool that the value has changed but I need to force reload to update the UI.

Not sure why this is. I get my comments as an object with a key of the parent elements id as a key and an array inside of it.

This is then converted inside of mapStateToProps.

Heres an image showing different stages of comments.

[image]

Anyone have any idea why this is.

Cheers, Petter

---

#### Action

```
export function pushVoteComment(option, postId) {
  const request = API.commentPostVote(option, postId)

  return dispatch => {
    request.then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({ type: COMMENTS_POST_VOTE, payload: data, meta: postId })
    })
  }
}
```

#### Reducer

```
const comments = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COMMENTS_GET_COMMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.meta]: action.payload,
      }
    case COMMENTS_POST_VOTE:
      console.log('An vote request was sent returning ', action.payload)
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

#### PostDetailes ( its used here to render a PostComment )

```
renderComments() {
    const { comments, post } = this.props
    console.log('This post has these comments: ', comments)
    return _.map(comments, comment => {
      return (
        <div key={comment.id} className="post-container">
          {post ? (
            <PostComment
              key={comment.id}
              postId={comment.id}
              body={comment.body}
              author={comment.author}
              voteScore={comment.voteScore}
              timestamp={comment.timestamp}
            />
          ) : (
            ''
          )}
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { posts, comments } = state
  return {
    comments: comments[ownProps.match.params.postId],
    post: posts.filter(
      item => item.id === ownProps.match.params.postId && item.deleted !== true
    )[0],
  }
}
```

#### PostComment

```
  <i
    className="fa fa-chevron-up"
    aria-hidden="true"
    onClick={() => pushVoteComment('upVote', postId)}
  />
  <span className="vote-amount">{voteScore}</span>
  <i
    className="fa fa-chevron-down"
    onClick={() => pushVoteComment('downVote', postId)}
  />

export default connect(null, { pushVoteComment })(PostComment)
```

#### PS:

The reason it is built with a {parentId: [{comment1}, {comment2}]}

Is that I use it when showing all posts to see a number of comments.

```
return ({comments.length})

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    comments: state.comments[ownProps.postId]
      ? state.comments[ownProps.postId]
      : [],
  }
}
```

#### Redux dev tool

Looks like this when I press the votebutton for the first time:

[image]

Then when I press again I get this:

[image]

Comment: Is your render function being called ?

Comment: No, its not beeing called after I press the votebutton (checked inside of `PostComment`)

Comment: @Dane added a image of my redux dev tool. To see a strange behavior.

Comment: then make sure that the `props` also get changed.. this usually arises when you mutate the redux store, but u dont seem to be doing so.. try consolelogging `this.props` too, just to make sure it is getting changed the way you want it to

Comment: from the devtools pics, looks like your actions are getting called twice... clearly unexpected behavior I presume ?

Comment: I updated the main console.log image, as you can see here looks like im getting the parent id one time to much. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that it's changing the state, not thinking about the fact that I have my comment stored as

```
{
  [postId]: [array of comments]
}
```

So in order to resolve it, I ended up rewriting my reducer doing it like this.

```
case COMMENTS_POST_VOTE:
  const { parentId } = action.payload // get commentId
  const commentList = [...state[parentId]] // get array of comments, but copy it
  const commentIndex = commentList.findIndex(el => (el.id === payload.id)) // get index of comment
  commentList[commentIndex] = action.payload // update the commentList
  const updatedPost = {...state, [parentId]: commentList} // return new state
  return updatedPost
```

Comment: One of the reasons to use some immutable struct library in your store. This would never happen then.